# no font file found in pygame fonts

Tags: python, pygame

This is the boiler plate code from a course that I am doing and when I run this, this error is showing up

```
C:\Users\Tanish\Desktop\Coding\cs50 ai>"C:/Program Files/Python39/python.exe" 
"c:/Users/Tanish/Desktop/Coding/cs50 ai/tictactoe/runner.py"
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.1)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last)

 File "c:\Users\Tanish\Desktop\Coding\cs50 ai\tictactoe\runner.py", line 18, in <module>
mediumFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 28)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf'
```

Although I have the font .ttf file in the same directory.

code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

import pygame

import tictactoe as ttt

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600, 400

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

mediumFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 28)
largeFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 40)
moveFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 60)
```

directory:
[image: folder image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to where you are running the file from.

Currently you are running it from `C:\Users\Tanish\Desktop\Coding\cs50 ai`. However, your `.tff` file is in `c:/Users/Tanish/Desktop/Coding/cs50 ai/tictactoe/`.

In `pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 28)`, you are telling the program to open the file from your current directory which of course does not exist.

A solution is to find the absolute path of your files:

```
import os, sys

ttf_path = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "OpenSans-Regular.ttf")
pygame.font.Font(ttf_path, 28)
```

Alternatively, you can run the code from inside `tictactoe/` directory.